# list USB device with specified VID and PID without using Windows driver Kit

Tags: visual-c++, usb

is there a way to find a USB device with specified VID and PID on windows without involve calling to WDK functions?

Comment: Use the SetupAPI: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550897%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list all attached USB devices in Visual C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735920/how-to-list-all-attached-usb-devices-in-visual-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below will do the trick:

```
static const char dongleVid[] = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '\0'};
static const char donglePid[] = {'5', '6', '7', '8', '\0'};
static const LPCTSTR arPrefix[3] = {TEXT("VID_"), TEXT("PID_"), TEXT("MI_")};

const std::string requiredVid = boost::to_upper_copy(std::string(arPrefix[0]) + std::string(dongleVid));
const std::string requiredPid = boost::to_upper_copy(std::string(arPrefix[1]) + std::string(donglePid));
unsigned i, j;

DWORD dwSize, dwPropertyRegDataType;
OSVERSIONINFO osvi;
CONFIGRET r;
HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;

TCHAR szDeviceInstanceID[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];
TCHAR szDesc[1024];
LPTSTR pszToken, pszNextToken;
TCHAR szVid[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN], szPid[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN], szMi[MAX_DEVICE_ID_LEN];

#ifdef UNICODE
FN_SetupDiGetDeviceProperty fn_SetupDiGetDeviceProperty = (FN_SetupDiGetDeviceProperty)
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Setupapi.dll")), "SetupDiGetDevicePropertyW");
#else
FN_SetupDiGetDeviceProperty fn_SetupDiGetDeviceProperty = (FN_SetupDiGetDeviceProperty)
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("Setupapi.dll")), "SetupDiGetDevicePropertyA");
#endif

// List all connected USB devices
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, TEXT("USB"), NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    return false;
}
// Find the ones that are driverless
for (i = 0; ; i++)
{
    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(DeviceInfoData);
    if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, &DeviceInfoData))
    {
        break;
    }

    r = CM_Get_Device_ID(DeviceInfoData.DevInst, szDeviceInstanceID , MAX_PATH, 0);
    if (r != CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        continue;
    }

    SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
                                          &dwPropertyRegDataType, (BYTE*)szDesc,
                                          sizeof(szDesc),   // The size, in bytes
                                          &dwSize);

    // Retreive the device description as reported by the device itself
    memset(&osvi, 0, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);

    pszToken = _tcstok_s(szDeviceInstanceID , TEXT("\\#&"), &pszNextToken);
    szVid[0] = TEXT('\0');
    szPid[0] = TEXT('\0');
    szMi[0] = TEXT('\0');
    while (pszToken != NULL)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (_tcsncmp(pszToken, arPrefix[j], lstrlen(arPrefix[j])) == 0)
            {
                switch (j)
                {
                    case 0:
                        _tcscpy_s(szVid, ARRAY_SIZE(szVid), pszToken);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        _tcscpy_s(szPid, ARRAY_SIZE(szPid), pszToken);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        _tcscpy_s(szMi, ARRAY_SIZE(szMi), pszToken);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        pszToken = _tcstok_s(NULL, TEXT("\\#&"), &pszNextToken);
    }


    std::string foundVid = boost::to_upper_copy(std::string(szVid));
    std::string foundPid = boost::to_upper_copy(std::string(szPid));

    if (requiredVid == foundVid && requiredPid == foundPid)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You never actually use the OSVERSIONINFO variable you declare.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simplified version of Guo Yanchao's code:

```
unsigned index;
HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData;
TCHAR HardwareID[1024];

// List all connected USB devices
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(NULL, TEXT("USB"), NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_ALLCLASSES);
for (index = 0; ; index++) {
    DeviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(DeviceInfoData);
    if (!SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, index, &DeviceInfoData)) {
        return false;     // no match
    }

    SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_HARDWAREID, NULL, (BYTE*)HardwareID, sizeof(HardwareID), NULL);

    if (_tcsstr(HardwareID, _T("VID_1234&PID_5678"))) {
        return true;     // match
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, you have all the necessary functions in Win32 API in user32.dll and setuapi.dll. This is a little C# sample:

```
internal static bool FindUsbDevice(string vendorId, string productId, 
        ref string deviceDesc, ref string deviceInstanceId, ref Guid classId)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        string enumeratorClass = "USB";
        IntPtr szClass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(enumeratorClass);
        Guid classGuid = Guid.Empty;
        IntPtr deviceInfoSet = new System.IntPtr();

        try
        {
            deviceInfoSet = DeviceManagement.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, szClass, IntPtr.Zero,
                DeviceManagement.DIGCF_ALLCLASSES | DeviceManagement.DIGCF_PRESENT);

            DeviceManagement.SP_DEVINFO_DATA spDevInfoData = new DeviceManagement.SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
            spDevInfoData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(spDevInfoData);

            for (int i = 0; DeviceManagement.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(deviceInfoSet, i, ref spDevInfoData); i++)
            {
                int nSize = 0;
                string DeviceInstanceId = new string('0', 259);
                IntPtr ptrDeviceInstanceId = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(DeviceInstanceId);

                if (!DeviceManagement.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(deviceInfoSet, ref spDevInfoData, ptrDeviceInstanceId,
                    DeviceInstanceId.Length, ref nSize))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId() error");
                    continue;
                }
                DeviceInstanceId = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptrDeviceInstanceId);

                if (!DeviceInstanceId.Contains(string.Format("USB\\VID_{0}&PID_{1}", vendorId, productId)))
                    continue;

                returnValue = true;
                deviceInstanceId = DeviceInstanceId;
                classId = spDevInfoData.ClassGuid;

                int DataT = 0;
                string buffer = new string('0', 259);
                IntPtr pBuffer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAuto(buffer);
                int bufferSize = 259;

                if (!DeviceManagement.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
                    deviceInfoSet, ref spDevInfoData, DeviceManagement.SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
                    ref DataT, pBuffer, bufferSize, ref bufferSize))
                {
                    if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == DeviceManagement.ERROR_INVALID_DATA)
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error invalid data");
                    else
                        Debug.WriteLine("error");
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pBuffer, bufferSize);
                    deviceDesc = buffer;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            DeviceManagement.SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(deviceInfoSet);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

while the wrapper code is:

```
   public sealed partial class DeviceManagement
{
    ///<summary >
    // API declarations relating to device management (SetupDixxx and 
    // RegisterDeviceNotification functions).   
    /// </summary>

    // from dbt.h

    internal const Int32 DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0X8000;
    internal const Int32 DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0X8004;
    internal const Int32 DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE = 5;
    internal const Int32 DBT_DEVTYP_HANDLE = 6;
    internal const Int32 DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES = 4;
    internal const Int32 DEVICE_NOTIFY_SERVICE_HANDLE = 1;
    internal const Int32 DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE = 0;
    internal const Int32 WM_DEVICECHANGE = 0X219;

    // from setupapi.h

    internal const Int32 DIGCF_PRESENT = 2;
    internal const Int32 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0X10;
    internal const Int32 DIGCF_ALLCLASSES = 0x4;
    internal const Int32 SPDRP_FRIENDLYNAME = 0xC;
    internal const Int32 SPDRP_DEVICEDESC = 0x0;
    internal const Int32 SPDRP_CLASSGUID = 0x8;

    // from WinError.h
    internal const Int32 ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 122;
    internal const Int32 ERROR_INVALID_DATA = 13;

    // Two declarations for the DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE structure.

    // Use this one in the call to RegisterDeviceNotification() and
    // in checking dbch_devicetype in a DEV_BROADCAST_HDR structure:

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE
    {
        internal Int32 dbcc_size;
        internal Int32 dbcc_devicetype;
        internal Int32 dbcc_reserved;
        internal Guid dbcc_classguid;
        internal Int16 dbcc_name;
    }

    // Use this to read the dbcc_name String and classguid:

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal class DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_1
    {
        internal Int32 dbcc_size;
        internal Int32 dbcc_devicetype;
        internal Int32 dbcc_reserved;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.U1, SizeConst = 16)]
        internal Byte[] dbcc_classguid;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 255)]
        internal Char[] dbcc_name;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
    {
        internal Int32 dbch_size;
        internal Int32 dbch_devicetype;
        internal Int32 dbch_reserved;
    }

    internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
    {
        internal Int32 cbSize;
        internal System.Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
        internal Int32 Flags;
        internal IntPtr Reserved;
    }

    internal struct SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA
    {
        internal Int32 cbSize;
        internal String DevicePath;
    }

    internal struct SP_DEVINFO_DATA
    {
        internal Int32 cbSize;
        internal System.Guid ClassGuid;
        internal Int32 DevInst;
        internal Int32 Reserved;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern IntPtr RegisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr hRecipient, IntPtr NotificationFilter, Int32 Flags);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, int MemberIndex, ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, IntPtr DeviceInstanceId, int DeviceInstanceIdSize, ref int RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern bool SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData, int Property, ref int PropertyRegDataType, IntPtr PropertyBuffer, int PropertyBufferSize, ref int RequiredSize);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(ref System.Guid ClassGuid, Int32 hwndParent);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Int32 SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Boolean SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, IntPtr DeviceInfoData, ref System.Guid InterfaceClassGuid, Int32 MemberIndex, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref System.Guid ClassGuid, IntPtr Enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, Int32 Flags);

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern Boolean SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(IntPtr DeviceInfoSet, ref SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA DeviceInterfaceData, IntPtr DeviceInterfaceDetailData, Int32 DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize, ref Int32 RequiredSize, IntPtr DeviceInfoData);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern Boolean UnregisterDeviceNotification(IntPtr Handle);
}
```

Hope it helps, you should quickly translate it into Visual C++