# Is it possible to write MBR of a pen drive by any hex editor?

Tags: operating-system, usb-drive, hex-editors, mbr

After creating the boot loader, if I copy the bytes of the boot loader and paste it on the 1st 512 bytes of the pen drive using a hex editor, will it work? (Actually I want to learn creating an operating system from scratch.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question, but to answer the title: yes. You can write to any part of the drive with an appropriately-designed hex editor with appropriate permissions (usually "sudo" access is required on Linux).

For instance, writing to the boot sector of a flash drive is necessary for automating booting of the [CHDK system](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/Prepare_your_SD_card).

Not all hex editors are designed to access drives, some can only work with files. For instance, the [NCurses Hexeditor](http://www.rogoyski.com/adam/programs/hexedit/) normally works only with files, but can be made to access disks as files in Linux/Unix environment by employing the `-d` flag.

The Linux `dd` command also enables low-level writing to drives. This may be useful in your case as it can be used to perform byte-by-byte copies of drive contents, including MBR sections.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your answer. I am actually more interested working on Windows rather than Linux although I know Linux is better for OS development. And I also am familiar with the dd command although I never tried it. In windows I am experienced with a free hex editor named [HxD]: http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/. It would be more helpful if you tell me whether I can do it in windows and which file system is good for doing this (NTFS of FAT32). Any tutorial link would be more preferable.

Comment: I'm sorry, @NafisAbdullahKhan, I'm not very familiar with Windows development tools.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know about HEX editors, but looks like on Windows you can try to `CreateFile` with name like this `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0` or just `\\PHYSICALDRIVE0`. And alter them with `WriteFile` (with caution!!! otherwise you can damage your OS install or other data).

You can probably figure out device name with [WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657). Also take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63878/Enumerate-and-Auto-Detect-USB-Drives) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735920/how-to-list-all-attached-usb-devices-in-visual-c).